# Сформировать последовательность An = N /(N + 1),где N = 1, 2, …, 20

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Сформировать последовательность, элементы которой вычисляются по формуле
**A<sub>N</sub> = N / (N + 1)**, где **N = 1, 2, …, 20**

Я совсем туплю, но как правильно написать код в C#

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++)
        (double)n / (n + 1);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Ну вы вычислили значения правильно, но ничему не присвоили результат или не вывели его в консоль

Comment: Создайте массив из 20 элементов и заполните вашими значениями. Потом выведите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно записать значения в массив `double[]`, а затем вывести в консоль.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 20;
    double[] nums = new double[n];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        nums[i - 1] = (double)i / (i + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Console.Write($"{nums[i]:F3} ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод

```
0.500 0.667 0.750 0.800 0.833 0.857 0.875 0.889 0.900 0.909 0.917 0.923 0.929 0.933 0.938 0.941 0.944 0.947 0.950 0.952
```